# Telegram: Import numbers with format .txt to telegram

Tags: desktop, telegram

I have a list numbers (about 2000 contacts) with format .txt
Now want add numbers to my telegram, best idea for add import list to telegram
idea is possible in desktop or Android?

Comment: You will reach rate limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with dekstop. Either convert the txt file to csv and download "import csv" from Play Store which will simply add all the contacts from your file and then you can see them in your telegram list (If they have Telegram) OR convert them to vcf and open it from your File manager, it will automatically add them into your contacts list.
Also if you search in Play Store you may find an application to directly import numbers from txt file.